# How can I find the total hits for an Elastic NEST query?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

In my application I have a query which brings limits the number of hits returned to 50 as follows

```
            var response = await client.SearchAsync<Episode>(s => s
                .Source(sf => sf
                     .Includes(i => i
                         .Fields(
                             f => f.Title,
                             f => f.PublishDate,
                             f => f.PodcastTitle
                         )
                     )
                     .Excludes(e => e
                         .Fields(f => f.Description)
                     )
                 )
                .From(request.Skip)
                .Size(50)
                .Query(q => q 
                    .Term(t => t.Title, request.Search) || q
                    .Match(mq => mq.Field(f => f.Description).Query(request.Search))));
```

> I am interested in the **total number of hits for the query (i.e. not limited to the size)**, so that I can deal with pagination on the front-end. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for `Total` property on the search response object. [Have a look](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/d43d12531b44b3a67c6a81b3c5e5d929992341f4/src/Nest/Search/Search/SearchResponse.cs#L118).

So in your particular case that will be `response.Total`.

Answer (score 6):

For those who are working on indices with more than 10000 documents, Elasticsearch will calculate total hits up to 10000 by default. To get around that, include `.TrackTotalHits(true)` in your query:

```
var resp = client.Search<yourmodel>(s => s
    .Index(yourindexname)
    .TrackTotalHits(true)
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll()));
```